# Why are static and transient members not fetch in Avro InduceSchemaTool from Java classes?

Tags: java, reflection, schema, avro

I am trying to create a avro schema from Java Class hierarchy . 
Before I deep dive in complete structure i tried to generate a Avro schema for a simple java class as below

```
package TestAvroTools;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public  class  InduceSchemaIPClass {

    private int inta;
    private String stringb;
    private ArrayList<String> a = null;
    private boolean booleana;

    private static class InnerKlass{
        int innerKlassInta;

    }

}
```

The Avro InduceScehmaTool (org.apache.avro.tool) (avro v1.7.7) (jdk 1.6) skip the static class member InnerKclass.
The output is as follows:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "InduceSchemaIPClass",
  "namespace" : "test.avro.ip",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "inta",
    "type" : "int"
  }, {
    "name" : "stringb",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "a",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : "string",
      "java-class" : "java.util.ArrayList"
    }
  }, {
    "name" : "booleana",
    "type" : "boolean"
  } ]
}
```

I debugged the code to find the statment which skip this in the ReflectData's getFields() (org.apache.avro.reflect)

```
for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields())
        if ((field.getModifiers() & (Modifier.TRANSIENT|Modifier.STATIC)) == 0)
```

Is there a reason why it is done so ? I need the static members to be a part of the Avro generate schema.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on the Apache Avro home page: "Apache Avro™ is a data serialization system.".

Now, let's open JLS 8.3.1.3. transient Fields: "Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object."

The same story for statics.

And the ReflectData source code states the following: "Return of this class and its superclasses to serialize."

So, the answer is: they are not part of the persistent state of an object, so there is no point to include these fields in a schema (from the tool perspective).

Comment: Thanks @Ivan for the explanation. I understand now that since transient and static aren't part of persistent state of object they are skipped by the tool. 
I didn't catch the significance of  :  _And the ReflectData source code states the following: "Return of this class and its superclasses to serialize."_

Comment: When it says Return of this class I understand that it means all members . Does that statement inherently specify Transient and Static are to be skipped somehow ?

Comment: All fields that are important from the serialization perspective I suppose.